# word usage in context

Tags: word-choice

**Example**: The Summer Scholars Program host 35 students within the last three years.

Is there a more appropriate word other than host?  Thank you.

Comment: Use _hosted_ to say the Program did that in the past, or _has hosted_ to say 'then and all the way up to today.'

Comment: ...has welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a form of 'host' is probably a good choice here. I looked up a summer scholars program to see what it involves. For example: http://miamioh.edu/admission/high-school/summer-scholars/

High school students are staying at the college facilities and being exposed to higher learning and experience some aspects of college life. It would be accurate to say that the college is hosting these students.

You could modify the sentence slightly:

The Summer Scholars Program **has hosted** 35 students **in** the last three years.